# HttpModule and older versions of IE

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, httpmodule

I've built an http module to log file downloads on a server. When a user downloads the file, it logs their IP, a file ID, download time, referrer, and user agent to the database. This works fine for the most part, although I've already had to deal with stripping out near-duplicates caused by download manager addons for Firefox by checking the Range header.

This hasn't solved the same problem for IE6 and IE7 users. When they initiate a download, it will repeatedly hit my module milliseconds apart and cause thousands of entries to be logged for a single file. It doesn't seem like older versions of IE are using the range header like Firefox does, and I'm not even sure that's the problem.

Anyone have any ideas as to what could be causing this, or what I should check to avoid the redundant requests from being logged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (or a similar web debugger) to see the requests that those particular flavors of IE sends to your server. Perhaps it is doing something legitimate, and perhaps you will be able to filter out the extra requests by looking at the HTTP headers and method.

Comment: Looking at the request headers hasn't shown me any useful information. They look very normal. They just have Connection=keep-alive, Accept, host, and user agent headers. 

I did notice that many of the problematic requests came from overseas. Is it possible that a shaky connection on their end might be resubmitting the download?